# Slide Js incorrect on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

https://www.fermento24.com/#
As you can see here, under the "I nuovi Vini" tab, there are 2 arrows to slide, while on pc it works fine, on mobile, due to resizing to show 2 products together instead of one the arrows do not work as intended. Is there a way to fix this so that, when clicking the arrows, it won't come up to a point that shows "blanks"?

Edit: Adding more detail:

https://jsfiddle.net/morganpubblicita/hryxau41/

```html
<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}"  data-section-type="product-tab-type-2" class="product-tab-type-2" >     
  {{ 'swiper.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'swiper.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

  <div class="full_width_tab">    
    <div class="grid-uniform">          

      <div class="container">      
        <div class="dt-sc-tabs-container-section"> 


          {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %} 
          <div class="dt-sc-tabs-container"> 


            <div class="dt-sc-tabs" style="float:left;width:100%;">   

              {% if section.settings.title != blank or section.settings.small_title != blank %}
              <div class="border-title wow fadeInDown animated">
                {% if section.settings.title != blank %}
                <h2 class="section-header__title" style="color:{{ section.settings.title_color }};margin-top:50px;">    
                  {{ section.settings.title }}
                </h2>
                {% endif %}      
                {% if section.settings.small_title != blank %}<div class="small-desc">  <p style="color:{{ section.settings.small_title_color }};">{{ section.settings.small_title }}</p></div>{% endif %}   
              </div>
              {% endif %}
              <div class="tab-title">
                {% for block in section.blocks %} 
                {% if block.settings.title != blank %}
                <div class="tab-link"><a href="#" class="tabs-{{ block.id }}">{{ block.settings.title }} </a></div>           
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
            {% for block in section.blocks %}
            {%- assign collection = collections[block.settings.collection] -%}               
            <div class="dt-sc-tabs-content" style="float:left;width:100%;"> 
              <div class="swiper-button">
                <div class="swiper-button-prev {{ block.settings.title | handleize }}" style="font-size:26px;"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next {{ block.settings.title | handleize }}" style="font-size:26px;"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-container {{ block.settings.title | handleize }}"> 
                <ul class="tab2  swiper-wrapper {{ block.id }}">
                  {% for product in collection.products %}
                  {% include 'home-product-grid-item' , grid_item_width: " " %}  
                  {% else %}
                  {% for i in (1..8) %}
                  <li class="grid__item swiper-slide item-row  on-sale" id="product-{{ i }}">
                    <div class="products product-hover-5">
                      <div class="product-container">
                        <a href="#" class="grid-link"> 
                          {% if forloop.index == 3 %}
                          <div class="featured-tag">
                            <span class="badge badge--sale">
                              <span class="gift-tag badge__text{% if sale_text.size > 7 %} badge__text--small{% endif %}">{{ 'products.product.sale' | t }}</span>
                            </span>
                          </div>{% endif %}

                          <div class="reveal"> 
                            {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
                            {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }} 
                          </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="ImageWrapper">
                          <div class="product-button">
                            <a href="#" class="quick-view-text"> 
                              <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="{{ product.url }}">                      
                              <i class="zmdi zmdi-link"></i>
                            </a>  
                            <form action="#" method="post" class="variants clearfix" id="cart-form-6529189125">
                              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="21661289093">
                              <a href="#" class="add-cart-btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-shopping-cart"></i> </a>
                            </form>
                            <a href="/account/login" class="wishlist"><i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite-outline"></i></a> 

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="product-detail"> 
                        <a href="#" class="grid-link__title">Sample title {{ i }}</a>

                        <div class="grid-link__meta">
                          <div class="product_price"> <span class="money" data-currency-usd="$320.00">$0.00</span> </div>
                          <del class="grid-link__sale_price"><span class="money" data-currency-usd="$756.00">$0.00</span></del> </div>
                        <span class="spr-badge" id="spr_badge_6529189125" data-rating="0.0"> 
                          <span class="spr-starrating spr-badge-starrating"><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty" style="color: #f05315;"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty" style="color: #f05315;"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty" style="color: #f05315;"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty" style="color: #f05315;"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty" style="color: #f05315;"></i></span> <span class="spr-badge-caption"> </span> </span>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  {% endfor %} 
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">                   
              var swiper = new Swiper('.{{ block.settings.title | handleize }}', {
                                      slidesPerView: 4,
                                      slidesPerColumn: 1,                  
                                      loop: false,
                                      pagination: {
                                      el: '.swiper-pagination',
                                      clickable: true,
                                      },
                                      navigation: {
                                      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next.{{ block.settings.title | handleize }}',
                                      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev.{{ block.settings.title | handleize }}',
                                      },

                                      breakpoints: {
                                      1024: {
                                      slidesPerView: 4,

                                      },
                                      768: {
                                      slidesPerView: 3,

                                      },
                                      640: {
                                      slidesPerView: 2,

                                      },
                                      567: {
                                      slidesPerView: 1,

                                      }
                                      },
                                      });               

            </script>
            {% endfor %}                
          </div><!--End tabs container-->
          {% endif %}
        </div>    
      </div>

    </div>
    <style>
      .product-tab-type-2 .full_width_tab .dt-sc-tabs  a { color:{{ section.settings.tag_clr }}; }

      .product-tab-type-2 .dt-sc-tabs-content .swiper-button-prev, .product-tab-type-2 .dt-sc-tabs-content .swiper-button-next {  color:{{ section.settings.arrow_text_clr }}; }
      .product-tab-type-2 .dt-sc-tabs-content .swiper-button-prev:hover, .product-tab-type-2 .dt-sc-tabs-content .swiper-button-next:hover {  color:{{ section.settings.arrow_text_hover_clr }}; }

    </style>
  </div> 
</div>

{% schema %}
{
"name": "Product Tab 1",
"class": "index-section",
"max_blocks": 4,
"settings": [

{
"type": "text",
"id": "title",
"label": "Heading",
"default": "New arrivals"
},  
{
"type": "color",
"id": "title_color",
"label": "Heading Color",
"default": "#000"
},  
{
"type": "text",
"id": "small_title",
"label": "Small Heading"
},
{
"type": "color",
"id": "small_title_color",
"label": "Small Heading Color",
"default": "#000"
},  
{
"type": "color",
"id": "tag_clr",
"label": "Tag Color",
"default": "#000"
},

{
"type": "color",
"id": "arrow_text_clr",
"label": "Arrow Text",
"default":"#000"

},
{
"type": "color",
"id": "arrow_text_hover_clr",
"label": "Arrow Hover Text",
"default":"#ff0069"

}





],
"blocks": [ 
{
"type": "text_block",
"name": "Column",
"settings": [
{
"type": "text",
"id": "title",
"label": "Collection Name",
"default": "Tab Name"
},  

{
"id": "collection",
"type": "collection",
"label": "Collection"
}   
]
}
],
"presets": [
{
"name": "Product Tab 1",
"category": "Collection",
"blocks": [
{
"type": "text_block"
}        
]
}
]
}
{% endschema %}
```

This is the js part that governs the size of each product and calls to the arrows. What I'd like to do is that, on mobile, it would move by single product and it wouldn't have a lot of white space left

Answer (score 0):

The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

But querySelector method uses CSS3 selectors for querying the DOM and CSS3 doesn't support ID selectors that start with a digit:

In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

Comment: don't use querySelector try with unique ids

Comment: How do i do that? as far as I've understood the arrows are related to the swiper.js..

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. Our colleague did a change while we were working, if you check now, it should work as intended and you should see what I was referring to before.